# Domain of a combined (quotient) function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Why is it that every book says the domain of a quotient functions $\frac{f}{g}$ is the intersection of the domains of $f$ and $g$ and the set of $x$ such that $g(x)\neq 0$.

Now in the following example $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x+2}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ the quotient is
$\frac{f}{g}(x)= \frac{x(x-1)}{x+2}$ according to my text book the domain is $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x\neq -2, 0 \}$ but I do not know why they exclude the point $x=0$.

They also say something similar in this post: [What is a combined function and what factors affect its domain.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531319/what-is-a-combined-function-and-what-factors-affect-its-domain/1531343#1531343)

Whta I am understanding is: If I simply see $\frac{x(x-1)}{x+2}$ as a function then the domain is every real number but $-2$; but If I see $\frac{x(x-1)}{x+2}$ as the quotient of $f$ and $g$ then I should also exclude the point $x=0$.

so what is the actual domain of $\frac{x(x-1)}{x+2}$

Comment: The point $0$ is not in the domain of $g$.

Comment: I know! but evaluating in the resulting quotient function gives the value 0, so is well defined!

Comment: The point is that $\frac{x(x-1)}{x+2}$ and $f(x)/g(x)$ are equal expressions only if $x\neq 0$. So their "domains" may be different at $x=0$.

Comment: @Novato I gave you a longer answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as "an actual domain" of a function. This is because a function is **defined** by its "rule" and its domain.

For example, the function

$$f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R\\
f:x\mapsto x^2$$

is **not the same function** as the function

$$g: \mathbb R\to\mathbb R\\
g: x\mapsto x^2$$

The two functions are not the same because their domains are not the same. Consequentially, their properties are also different. $f$ is an injective (one-to-one) function, while $g$ is not.

---

Conclusion:

Asking "what is the actual domain of $x^2$" is not a sensible question.

---

However, we can still speak of "the maximal possible domain" of a function. For example, $x^2$ is defined for every real $x$, so we could say that the maximal domain of $x^2$ is $\mathbb R$

> **WARNING**: this is not a mathematically well defined term, as we could easily argue that the maximal domain of $x^2$ is $\mathbb C$ or some other set which includes $\mathbb R$.

In that case, the "maximal domain" of the function $\frac{x(x-1)}{x+2}$ would be $\mathbb R\setminus\{-2\}$, you are correct. However, the function defined as the quotient of $f$ and $g$ is again, a function defined by both its **rule** and its **domain**. And by definition, the domain of $\frac fg$ is $D_f\cap D_g\cap \{x\in D_g: g(x)\neq 0\}$, so, by *definition*, the function $\frac fg$ in your case is the function

$$\frac fg: \mathbb R\setminus\{-2,0\}\to\mathbb R\\
\frac fg: x\mapsto{x(x-1)}{x+2}$$

So sure, the domain of this function is not the "maximum domain", and you can find a function with a bigger domain and the same rule, but... so what? Nobody ever said that that's not possible.